# Creating a Mono-Only Bell Timbre in Cakewalk

Tags: daw, production, audio, sound-design, mono

[This video](https://youtu.be/wLcqQOJmnio?t=895) outlines the production a sort of bell timbre which can only be heard when played in mono.  I am trying to reproduce this in Cakewalk.

I think I've figured out how to make the correlated noise audible in stereo and not mono.  I use Serum to create the noise, add a "Channel Tools" Audio Effect in which I turn the "Mid Gain" knob to -∞, and set the track in Console View to "Interleave = Mono."

The instruction I'm stuck on is (16:29 in the video)...

> Now what we're going to do is take a narrow frequency band only on one
> side and we're going to flip the phase.  What happens then when you
> combine to mono is that everything goes away except for that narrow
> band where you flip the phase because it's no longer canceling in the
> left and right channels.  By employing this trick over and over again
> we can actually play a little bit of a melody.

I've found how to flip the phase of the track in Console View, but not how to apply the phase flip to a specific side or frequency band.  What steps do I need to take to emulate this sound?

Comment: Note:  I may have been mistaken in my explanation of the first stage of the process.  I will edit this question some time in the future after I have learned a bit more about the subject.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably simplest to use two identical mono tracks; that way you don't need split-function stereo effects.

Then you can just EQ one track & flip the phase.